# Sending multiple objects in HTTP Request (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm currently "migrating" from SOAP to REST services. (legacy code)

There are several methods that send objects in the request, the objects vary in type and number, I'd like to do something like this.

```
public long getRelationship(@RequestBody RelationshipDirection relationshipDirection,
@RequestBody List<long> ids, @RequestBody BigInteger skipCount){
    /*do something*/
}
```

And then there is another method that needs just 2 objects, and one is 'Extension' type.

From similar questions I know that I need a **wrapper object**, but I would need one for each possible combination of parameter number and types, so my question here is:

*Is there another solution for this?* , something like a "Generic container"?

Comment: This is a complicated question without knowing more details.  Are you saying its impossible to know which objects are in a given request without examining the request body?

Comment: and how your SOAP request looks like? is there Root element, isn't it? And answer no, there is no such thing like "Generic container" if you do not define it. And it will be that "wrapped object" anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this ?

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/some-post-endpoint", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void post(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) 
    throws Exception {

  System.out.println(payload);

}
```

I think Map is a generic enough container.

Comment: I have to test it but for now, Map seems to be working fine!